# Reverse CSS Counter with Bootstrap 5.2

Tags: bootstrap-5, css-counter

I have two ordered-lists that I am displaying - one is ascending and the other descending. Currently, the HTML attribute "reversed" is poorly supported, and it seems Bootstrap's [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/list-group/#numbered) recommends using CSS for their counters, but I am having a difficult time understanding how to accomplish a descending order with dynamic lists. Most examples I see online suggest hard-coding the number to start, but again, my lists are dynamic.

I don't want to change the style of the content, so I don't think there is a need to manipulate "content", correct? Here is what my CSS looks like currently

```
ol.history {
    counter-reset: descendingList ;
}

ol.history li::before {
    counter-increment: descendingList -1;
}
```

Where my HTML code looks like

```
<ol class="list-group list-group-numbered mb-3 history">
   <li class="list-group-item"></li>
   <li class="list-group-item"></li>
</ol>
```

Do I need to utilize javascript to accomplish this? Also, I know that since CSS counters are 0-base, I need to add an additional increment somewhere to make my last `list-group-item` be 1.

**UPDATE**

Just to expand upon this...

What if I have two ordered-lists, `<ol>`, and I want to combine both lists for the count; however, I want the second, bottom list to begin the sequence in descending order, then the first list continues, but in ascending order.

It would look something like this...

[image]

Comment: Try using javascript http://jsfiddle.net/sYSEJ/4/

Comment: Thanks; however, I was really hoping I could utilize CSS so I did not have to run the script every time I have an AJAX update where this list may change.

Would I still be able to accomplish this with the order broken like I show? (see my Update) Thanks